# Docker port forwarding not working

Tags: docker, portforwarding, docker-container

I have setup Docker container for access my machine docker container to another machine in local.

Create a container below command:

```
    docker run -it -d --name containerName -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html -p 7000:8000 --net mynetwork --ip 172.11.0.10 --privileged myimagename bash
```

After Create A Container Details:

```
        CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES

        1e1e5e9b74b4        myimgaename         "bash"              21 minutes ago      Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7000->8000/tcp   containername
```

NetWork Details:

```
     "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "fe357c54c816fff0f9d642037dc9a173be7f7e42a80776d006572f6a1395969e",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "7000"
                }
            ]
        }
```

if I access docker  ipaddr(172.11.0.10) or hostname(www.myhost.net) in mymachine(hostmachine) it working

But if I access with **Port** doesn't work: hostmachine ip: 192.168.1.1

```
  go to the browser  192.168.1.1:7000  hostmachine and locally connected anoter machine also.
```

But My 7000 port are listen in hostmachine:

```
        # ps aux | grep 7000
        root     10437  0.0  0.2 194792 24572 pts/0    Sl+  12:33   0:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 7000 -container-ip 172.11.0.10 -container-port 8000
        root     10941  0.0  0.0 118492  2324 pts/3    R+   12:44   0:00 grep --color=auto 7000
```

**update 1:**

```
      $ docker version
        Client:
         Version:      1.11.2
         API version:  1.23
         Go version:   go1.5.4
         Git commit:   b9f10c9
         Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:39:21 2016
         OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

        Server:
         Version:      1.11.2
         API version:  1.23
         Go version:   go1.5.4
         Git commit:   b9f10c9
         Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:39:21 2016
         OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Suggest me Why Cannot access my Container to another machine. How to Resolve this Problem

Comment: Are you using docker toolbox or native docker?

Comment: @Shiraaz.M   I am using  native docker, I install using command line(fed23)     dnf install docker

Answer (score 186):

A very common problem can be this:

Bind your **app** inside Docker to **0.0.0.0**, not to **127.0.0.1** address to let Docker reach the app inside container.

*UPD: Don't try to solve it with `docker`. There is **no docker command** to fix that. It strictly depends on the using app, web-framework, etc. Read the manual of the tool you use inside the container. Try to google "how to bind **[using framework]** to the specific address and port". It could be an environment variable, cli parameter, code, etc.*

Comment: Thanks! `0.0.0.0` it the key. My example was simple php standalone server: `d run --rm -p 8091:8091 -v (pwd):(pwd) -w (pwd) --name php php:7.3 php -S 0.0.0.0:8091`

Comment: What does this mean? Do not use only english. Post full docker commands.

Comment: @mathtick It doesn't require any special docker command, but you should bind the socket of your app to `0.0.0.0` address. It depends on the app you use inside a container. For example if you have a nodejs app you should set `host` parameter in `server.listen` function call to `0.0.0.0`: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

Comment: Oh I see, it is "tell the app to bind" and not "tell docker to bind the app" got it.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Slightly simplified explanation: Your networking application have to be attached to IP address to let other apps/browsers/servers/users can discover it for connection. `0.0.0.0` IP address means your app will be attached to all IP addresses you have. `127.0.0.1` IP address is private and doesn't available outside. Since your app runs in a container than your host is the outside world for it and you have to attach the socket to the *external* address `0.0.0.0` of the container to let your host connect to it.

Comment: Your programming language has API to set IP address for the server socket of your app. For example in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind

Comment: I'm using Rails and I need to use `bin/rails server --binding 0.0.0.0` instead of `bin/rails server`

Comment: I'm using Ghost and I needed to set `server__host="0.0.0.0"` in my `.env` file (or the equivalent in the conffig gile)

Comment: for flask i added host='0.0.0.0' in app.run() then it started working

Comment: This is a truly great answer! I was running a bunch of kubernetes services inside a docker and the default forward is to ```127.0.0.1```which of cause must be manually changed to something like ```kubectl port-forward svc/kiali --address=0.0.0.0 20001 -n istio-system``` Thank you for the critical hint (and for asking the question)

Comment: Finally, the solution to my problem!

Comment: thanks very much! this is a bug confusing me for a while

Comment: can you clearly provided the solution as a command?

Comment: The command depend on what inside the container. I've added a little an explanation to the answer.

Comment: For Django dev server, use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` instead of just `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: for uvicorn running inside the container, need to change and add host parameter `uvicorn src.main:app --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload` else by default it listens on `127.0.0.1`
`

Answer (score 29):

Port `7000` on the host is redirecting to port `8000` in the container, but is anything listening on that port in the container?

Your `docker run` command is a bit odd: `-it` is for running a container interactively with a terminal attached; `-d` is for running detached, in the background; `bash` at the end overrides whatever the image configures as the startup command, which is why I think there's nothing listening on port `8000`.

Try running the simplest NGINX container with this:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx:alpine
```

And then verify you can get to the homepage:

```
curl http://localhost:8081
```

If that's working then I'd look at how you're running your image.

Comment: In my case localhost:8081 does not working. I have to use docker-machine ip default instead (192.168.99.100). Any idea why localhost is not working ?

Comment: When you use Docker "natively", containers are "bound" to the host computer, so you use `localhost`. When you use an alternative like Docker Toolbox, Docker runs inside a VM, so the containers are "bound" to the VM's `localhost` and you need to use its IP address (usually `192.168.99.100`)

Answer (score 3):

This was happening for me w/ Docker for Mac.  Clicking the Docker icon, then `Restart` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

#### For anyone running serverless-offline inside a docker container:

I was trying to map localhost:3000 on my mac to the default serverless-offline app port of 3000 (which was running inside docker), achieved the desired result as follows:

(1) Added `--host:0.0.0.0` to the usual serverless offline command like so:

```
serverless offline --host 0.0.0.0
```

(2) Then ran the docker container with the usual port mapping:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 <your-image-name>
```

NOTE: Needed to rebuild my image (before running it) to get everything working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have encountered this problem as I'm using Dockerfile to build image. I realised I can't set address to specific IP address meaning after I change

```
    srv := &http.Server{
    Handler: s,
    Addr:    "127.0.0.1:5000",
}
```

to

```
    srv := &http.Server{
    Handler: s,
    Addr:    ":5000",
}
```

the command `docker run -dp 5000:5000 --name myapiserver api_server:v1` is working properly.
I can access the the container port 5000 without issue. So to conclude in container you can only set the server's port?

**Update**

127.0.0.1 is the IP address that your host will not send to outsite, the proper way to handler way is to send through all IP address which is 0:0:0:0 or in short just port only.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem with a Docker Wordpress container.

### Troubleshooting:

`curl -Is http://192.168.X.X` executed on the Docker host itself would return a result as expected, but the same command executed on my laptop on a different subnet would just hang.

Same with `telnet 192.168.X.X 80`: this would connect as expected on port 80 from the Docker host itself, but not outside the Docker host; it too would just hang.

`docker logs containerName` provided no useful clues.

On the router's firewall I allowed everything between the Docker host and my laptop to ensure the router's firewall wasn't breaking connectivity on port 80.

### Solution:

Struggling to clear the error, I decided to remove my custom networking from the `docker run` command to reduce complexity.

Like the OP, I had specified my own custom network and IP address in the `docker run` command. But when I removed `--net` and `--ip` from the `docker run` command, the container rose-up using the default bridge and a Docker DHCP assigned address.

### Test Solution:

I found the IP of my Wordpress container using:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' wordpressContainerName
```

and tried loading Wordpress in a browser on my laptop. The container could now be contacted on the forwarded port 80 outside the Docker host on a different subnet.

### Conclusion:

Removing `--net` and `--ip` from the `docker run` command fixed the issue in my case; YMMV of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9000:4000 --name some-container some-image-name` or you can use `-it` flag

Answer (score 0):

After thousand of hours digging this problem, i finally solve it by this silly way:

1. Uninstalled docker:

> sudo yum remove docker 
> docker-client 
> docker-client-latest 
> docker-common 
> docker-latest 
> docker-latest-logrotate 
> docker-logrotate 
> docker-engine
> docker-ce

2. Update my centos system:

   yum -y update
3. Reboot
4. Re-install docker
5. Re-install container/image

Now it work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I logged in the docker container (postgresql) and saw that it's ip was 172.18.0.13 (by running ifconfig or ip a, install by e.g. apt-get install net-tools if you are running Debian derived containers).

I was able to connect to the container from the host machine fine (netcat, install by running apt-get install netcat-traditional) :

```
nc -vz 172.18.0.13 5432
```

but trying to connect from outside to the exposed port 5433 did not work.

Next I checked the iptables -settings:

```
iptables -nL -t nat --line-numbers |grep 5433
```

and saw output

```
7   DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5433 to:172.18.0.2:5433
```

So the IP address of the port forwarding is pointing to docker_gwbridge (or wrong ip). I think there is some older container lingering around, or the port forward settings of it, or some malfunction in docker gwbridge. Restarting docker might help, and/or clearing/flushing all iptables -settings before starting docker. However, I had some production containers running there and I tried to avoid service break, so I fixed it manually by deleting the offending rule (line 7):

```
iptables -t nat -D DOCKER-INGRESS 7
```

Then I manually added forward to the right container (Note! please change the interface -i to your egress interface):

```
iptables -t nat -I DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 5433 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.13:5432
```

Please note that this is a temporary hack, since docker keeps changing the rule back to a non-working version, so restart might be required sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

one possible issue is that your container is using IPV6 , after running your container , for example if you are running you container using something like this >

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --name mycontainer myimage
```

then run this in bash of your host machine >

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
```

if there was **tcp6** in the output , it means that your container is using IPV6

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple just check your ip of the docker by
docker-machine ip

it usually 192.168.99.100

first create a docker conatiner abd run it by
docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx:alpine

then run
http://192.168.99.100:8081/ on your browser.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Partial Answer:**

Now I solved this problem partially, While i try without **bash** in create a container  and change my **port to 3000(-p 3000:80)** it worked for me.

Before Command:

```
     docker run -it -d --name containerName -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html -p 3000:80 --net mynetwork --ip 172.11.0.10 --privileged myimagename  bash
```

After Command:

```
    docker run -it -d --name containerName -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html -p 3000:80 --net mynetwork --ip 172.11.0.10 --privileged myimagename
```

Then,

execute the container with **bin/bash**

```
  docker exec -it containerName bin/bash
```

Now , works locally Connected Another machine.

```
 hostmachineip:3000 


I don't know docker have any port restrictions.But This solution works for me.
```

Answer (score -1):

When i encountered this problem (with a docker-compose managed set of docker instances), I found that deleting the network that docker-compose fixed the problem:

```
docker-compose stop
# find the network related to my docker-compose setup
docker network ls
docker network rm NETWORKNAME
# let docker-compose recreate the network:
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: `docker-compose down` does all that

Comment: it does, and more? I don't lose volumes, containers or images by doing the above (just the network)?