# Binding to Heroku dynamic $PORT and keep getting error?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, heroku

I keep getting this error from the heroku logs:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 app that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku. This is what I do at startup:

```
if (!int.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"), out var port))
{ port = 5000; }

return WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
    });
```

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

CMD dotnet MyApp.dll
```

I can see the app is starting OK, I even see it's successfully binding to something like `http://127.0.0.1:48684` which means it's getting the `$PORT`, but at the time of a request I get the above error. I cannot use `EXPOSE $PORT` because it's given at run time.

I've been wrestling with this for a while now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens that after a few minutes posting this question I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427805/4152153) which solves my problem. I changed the listen options to `options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port);`.

```
if (!int.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"), out var port))
{ port = 5000; }

return WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port);
    });
```